# Django sort queryset by related model field

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following models (abbreviated for clarity):

```
class Order(models.Model):
    some fields

class OrderStatus(models.Model):
    order = models.ForiegnKey(Order)
    status = models.CharField(choices=['ORDERED', 'IN_TRANSIT', 'RECEIVED'])
    time = models.DateTimeField()
```

**I would like to sort all Orders that contain all three OrderStatuses by their order received time.**

In other words, select the orders that have records of Ordered, In Transit, and Received like so:

```
Order.objects.filter(orderstatus__status=OrderStatus.ORDERED)
             .filter(orderstatus__status=OrderStatus.IN_TRANSIT)
             .filter(orderstatus__status=OrderStatus.RECEIVED)
```

... and then sort them by the `time` field of their related `OrderStatus` model for which `status=OrderStatus.RECEIVED`.

This is where I'm stuck. I have read the Django docs on the `.extra()` queryset modifier and direct SQL injection, but I'm still at a loss. Could I achieve it with an annotated field and `Q` objects or am I better going the `.extra` route?

Comment: Interesting problem, and no idea how to solve it. But I'm curious about the design. In your model it looks like each order can be ordered, in transit and received multiple time. Is this what you intend? Or are there constraints that are not shown? (You did mention that it is abbreviated for clarity.) Also can an order be RECEIVED without having been ORDERED and IN_TRANSIT first?

Comment: @Alain good observations, but yes we have front end and back end constraints around this. Allows for greater insights into data and analytics. Business case would be that each order only has one of each status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't you try to do like this?

```
Order.objects.filter(orderstatus__status=OrderStatus.ORDERED)
             .filter(orderstatus__status=OrderStatus.IN_TRANSIT)
             .filter(orderstatus__status=OrderStatus.RECEIVED)
             .order_by('orderstatus__time')
```

On my models it worked as expected - `order_by` picked the last joined orderstatus just as you need. If you're not sure you can check the real query like this (in django shell):

```
from django.db import connection
# perform query
print(connection.queries)
```

Also it can be done like this:

```
OrderStatus.objects.filter(status=OrderStatus.RECEIVED)
                   .order_by('time').select_related('order')
                   .filter(order__orderstatus__status=OrderStatus.ORDERED)
                   .filter(order__orderstatus__status=OrderStatus.IN_TRANSIT)
```